# Difference between 'sum % 2' and 'sum % 2 == 0' in array summing function

Tags: javascript, function

Solving a code wars problem and I realized I'm confused how the remainder operator (%) works. Which boolean is returned when you have an expression like `10 % 2` vs `9 % 2`?

Here is the original code wars question:

> Given a list of integers, determine whether the sum of its elements is odd or even.
>
> Give your answer as a string matching "odd" or "even".
>
> If the input array is empty consider it as: [0] (array with a zero).

Both of the following solutions seem to work

```
function oddOrEven(array) {

  let sum = array.reduce( (acc, c) => acc + c, 0 )

  return sum % 2 ? "odd" : "even"

}
```

```
function oddOrEven(array) {

  let sum = array.reduce( (acc, c) => acc + c, 0 )

  return sum % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd"

}
```

So what exactly does a remainder expression like `sum % 2` return? If my understanding of a ternary is correct the remainder expression would have to return true when there is a remainder because the first solution works correctly.

Comment: You are dividing by 2, so the only possible remainders are 1 and 0. And in JS `1 = true` and `0 = false`. In fact any non-zero value would evaluate to true.

Comment: the remainder operator a % b returns (surprise) the remainder of the division a/b. For example, `42 % 10` would be `2`

Comment: @PrerakSola: `the only possible remainders are 1 and 0` - not true, `-5 % 2` is `-1`

Answer (score 0):

The result of `%` is a reminder and not a `boolean` value.
For example:

```
if sum = 0
then sum % 2 === 0

if sum = 1
then sum % 2 === 1

if sum = 2
then sum % 2 === 0
```

Therefore, you should compare the result of `%` to a specific value if you want to obtain a `boolean`.

Comment: But if `sum % 2 === 1` then also `sum % 2 == true` and  `!!(sum % 2) === true` and `Boolean(sum % 2) === true`. It depends on coding style. ;-)

Comment: @RobG when you compare `sum % 2` to anything, you are forcing JS to decide if the result of `sum % 2` is matching to `true` or `false`. The result of `%` itself is always a `number` not a `boolean`. In all your examples, you can substitute `sum % 2` with `1` and get the same result. Talking about coding style, `sum % 2 == true`, `!!(sum % 2) === true` and `Boolean(sum % 2) === true` are good examples of how you should never write your code if you want to keep it clear and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I figured out my own question. According to the MDN:

> The conditional (ternary) operator is the only JavaScript operator that takes three operands: a condition followed by a question mark (?), then an expression to execute if the condition is truthy followed by a colon (:), and finally the expression to execute if the condition is falsy.

Truthy is defined as

> All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy. That is, all values are truthy except false, 0, -0, 0n, "", null, undefined, and NaN.

For context, this is the most popular solution when I look at the solutions list on code wars:

```
function oddOrEven(arr) { return arr.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0) % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; }
```

And I believe the reason it works is because if a+b % 2 results in 1, and we know 1 is truthy according to the mdn, the ternary expression will return 'odd.' If a+b % 2 results in -1, we also know -1 is truthy per the mdn, so the ternary expression will return 'odd.' If a+b % 2 results in 0, we know 0 is falsy again according to the mdn, so the ternary expression will return 'even.'